# Railsの開発をpowderを用いて行いたいが、powderが機能しない

Tags: ruby-on-rails

こんにちは、RailsでWebアプリの開発を行っております。
普段はrails -sコマンドでlocalhostにアクセスし、実行しておりますが、
powder コマンドを利用してプロジェクトごとにURLを変更しようとしております。

```
$ rails new demo_proj -d mysql
$ rails g scaffold book title:string price:integer
$ rake db:create
$ rake db:migrate # ここまではよくあるコマンド
$ rails -s # ここをpowder linkとしたい
```

ですが、コマンドを実行したところ下記のような結果になりました。

```
$ powder link
  Pow is not installed. That is, the ${HOME}/.pow symlink does not exist.
$ brew install pow
  Warning: pow-0.5.0 already installed
```

osはYOSEMITEなのですが、似たような症状の方がいらっしゃらなかったので
質問させていただきます。

また、念のためpowderのバージョンも確認しましたので、連携致します。

```
$ gem list | grep powder
  powder (0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

僕もpow / powderを使っていますが、brewではインストールしていません。

公式ページにある

```
curl get.pow.cx | sh
```

でインストールしています。

これで試すとどうなりますか？

参考 http://pow.cx

#### 追記

Powderを使わなくてもPow単体でも使うことができます。  
原因を切り分けるためにPow単体で動かしてみてください。

以下のようにシンボリックリンクを作ってください。  
`/path/to/myapp`はRailsアプリが存在するパスです。

```
$ cd ~/.pow
$ ln -s /path/to/myapp
```

その後、 http://myapp.dev にアクセスするとどうなりますか？

あと、Powの調子が悪い時はPCを再起動すると直る、という話も時々聞きます。  
こちらも試してみてください。

#### 追記2

> "Application not found"とブラウザ上で表示されました。

ちょっと古いですが、こちらに同じような議論があります。

https://github.com/basecamp/pow/issues/145

ここを読むと、`~/.pow`が`/Users/(あなたのアカウント名)/Library/Application Support/Pow/Hosts`のシンボリックリンクになっているか確認しろ、とあります。

元から`~/.pow`ディレクトリが存在していたりすると"Application not found"になるようです。

あと、1つのマシンに複数のアカウントがログインしていて、それらがPowを使っている場合もNGみたいですね。  
1つのアカウントでログインすると直った、と書いてあります。

akira noguchiさんの症状と合致するものあるかもしれないので、上のissueをじっくり読んでみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

念のため、brewでアンインストール、
公式ページのアンインストールの方法を行いました。

その後、こちらで案内して頂いたものを実行後にpowder linkを
行いましたが結果は同じものでした。

Comment: "Application not found"とブラウザ上で表示されました。

Comment: ~/.powが元からあったのが悪かったようです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: akira noguchiさん、解決して良かったです！今後この質問を読んだ人がぱっと解決策を確認できるように、僕の回答にベストアンサーマーク（緑のチェックマーク）を付けてもらえると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 0):

自分の場合は、一度`powder install`をやってから、`powder restart`したらうまくいきました

Comment: ありがとうございます。
うーん、こちらも試してみましたが変わりませんでした。